# what is a smarter way to pass amCharts data

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I think that jQuery is not mandatory for using amCharts. What is the advantage of using jQuery with amCharts?

Regarding the data used in amCharts, is there a more "less coding" way to pass data to it (instead of repeating over and over the columns being used) ?

`var chartData = [{
                country: "USA",
                visits: 4025,
                color: "#FF0F00"
            }, {
                country: "China",
                visits: 1882,
                color: "#FF6600"
            }, { etc....`

and Finally, is there a smarter way to build chartS instead of defining each and every ONE over and over (an issue for dynamically generated charts) ?

`

```
            // second graph                              
            graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph.title = "North America";
            graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
            graph.valueField = "namerica";
            graph.type = "column";
            graph.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph.fillAlphas = 1;
            graph.lineColor = "#D8E0BD";
            chart.addGraph(graph);

            // thirdt graph              
            graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph.title = "Asia-Pacific";
            graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
            graph.valueField = "asia";
            graph.type = "column";
            graph.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph.fillAlphas = 1;
            graph.lineColor = "#B3DBD4";
            chart.addGraph(graph);

            // fourth graph 
            graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph.title = "Latin America";
            graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
            graph.valueField = "lamerica";
            graph.type = "column";
            graph.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph.fillAlphas = 1;
            graph.lineColor = "#69A55C";
            chart.addGraph(graph);

            // fifth graph 
            graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph.title = "Middle-East";
            graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
            graph.valueField = "meast";
            graph.type = "column";
            graph.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph.fillAlphas = 1;
            graph.lineColor = "#B5B8D3";
            chart.addGraph(graph);

            // sixth graph  
            graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph.title = "Africa";
            graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
            graph.valueField = "africa";
            graph.type = "column";
            graph.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph.fillAlphas = 1;
            graph.lineColor = "#F4E23B";
            chart.addGraph(graph);
```

`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like that you are new to programming, and or you have gotten away with just writing simple scripts. i suggest to start reading on design patterns, a bit of OOP and how abstraction of code works.

There is no silver bullet to achieve what you ask, it can be done in a million ways.

Now coming back to your question, perhaps you can create a function that creates a graph with common configuration and using passed properties.

```
function createGraph(title, valueField, color){
        var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
        graph.title = title;
        graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
        graph.valueField = valueField;
        graph.type = "column";
        graph.lineAlpha = 0;
        graph.fillAlphas = 1;
        graph.lineColor = color;

}


var chart = Amcharts....;
var graphlist = [...];
for(int x = 0; x < graphlist; x++){
    chart.add(createGraph(graphList[x].title, graphList[x].valueField, graphList[x].color));
}
```

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I used to use amcharts one of the best way is to use the data loader plugin and load data from CSV or data from any URL.this keeps the code less and it can also changed very frequently depending on the file or URL.

[The data loader plugin information will be available here](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/using-data-loader-plugin/)